# Calculate power of large numbers mathematically?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Is there a short-hand method to find the value of a number with a large power.
For example : 1024^2048

Comment: It might be helpful if you explained a bit as to why you need to do this? The practical answer varies depending on the purpose. Generally you want either the first so many digits, last so many digits or the modulus rather than 6000+ digits. There are exponentiation algorithms that'll allow you to do it O(log N) multiplications where N = 2048. However, the question remains, why? Not saying so is probably one of the reasons for your down votes. This may be a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you do not want *large power exact value*, but *mod power*.

C# examples (it's StackOverflow, so a kind code is expected):

```
// Exact value
BigInteger a = BigInteger.Pow(1024, 2048);
// Mod Power (a^b mod 3) much more popular
BigInteger b = BigInteger.Pow(1024, 2048, 7);  // <- mod 7
```